# Printing from inside a Windows 7 VM via Virtualbox 4.3 with 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualbox, 64-bit

I have installed Windows 7 64-bit as VM. I am unable to install my printer in Windows 7. USB is working and all extensions and guest additions are installed.
USB ports are shown in virtual machine, but printing does not happen.

I have tried through various updates of Virtualbox and Ubuntu, but it does not work.

*finally checked usb mode entry in usb/-modeswitch.conf file - changed it. all is working fine.*

Comment: Care to write your solution in an own answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the older version of Virtual box VirtualBox-4.2.16-86992-Win.exe as the newer version fails when trying to install 12.04 LTS.  I learned the hard way NOT to get the upgrade to 4.3 (which does not work at all).  I guess I could upload this version somewhere on Ubuntu or send a copy to you via email 10megs, not big. good luck finding an older version of virtual box, pre 4.3  C.C.